# Okhttp exception

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a request and get the json response to a json string but every time i execute this it gives me an exception. Please help me.

```
public String login(String json) throws IOException {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Agent agent = gson.fromJson(json, Agent.class);
        json = gson.toJson(agent, Agent.class);
        String url = "http://laravel-zona-azul.herokuapp.com/api/v1/login";

        Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();

        builder.url(url);

        MediaType mediaType =
                MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, json);

        builder.post(body)
        .addHeader("login", agent.login)
        .addHeader("cache-control", agent.password);
        Log.d("MYAPP", "Body: " + body);
        Request request = builder.build();
        try{
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().string();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return "";
    }
```

Comment: What the Exception ? Add it with question

Comment: I  post my answer have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this it's working fine for me.**

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response != null)
                    try {
                        response.body().string();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        });
```

**Instead of Using this**

```
try{
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().string();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```